# Creating generic from two other generics

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use two generics `DeepMerge` and `Confine` to create a single `ConfineDeepMerge`.

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends (infer U)[]
    ? DeepPartial<U>[]
    : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
      ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
      : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};

type ConfineExtention<A, B> = { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? (DeepPartial<A>[K]) : never };
type Confine<A, B extends ConfineExtention<A, B>> = B;

type DeepMerge<T, U> = [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U;

type ConfineDeepMerge<A, B> = Confine<A, DeepMerge<A, B>>;
```

[image]

> Type 'DeepMerge' does not satisfy the constraint 'ConfineExtention>'.
>     Type 'B | { [K in keyof (B & Pick>)]: K extends keyof B ? K extends keyof A ? DeepMerge : B[K] : K extends keyof A ? A[K] : never; }' is not assignable to type 'ConfineExtention>'.
>       Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'ConfineExtention>'. [2344]

How can I merge these two generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what you want... who knows, maybe this:

```
type ConfineMerge<T, C extends {
  [K in keyof C]: K extends keyof T ? (Partial<T>[K]) : never
}> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof C>> & C;
```

If you could edit the question to explain what you're trying to do it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the question needs more clarity. Is there any way to use the two generics to form the third?

Comment: I updated it to reflect the recent most issue. Still just trying to find a way to plug these things together.

Answer (score 0):

This works but is very verbose:

```
type Merge<M, N> = Omit<M, Extract<keyof M, keyof N>> & N;
// type Confine<A, B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : never }> = B;
type ConfineMerge<T, C extends ExtentionForConfineMerge<T, C>> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof C>> & C;
type ExtentionForConfineMerge<T, C> = {[K in keyof C]: K extends keyof T ? (Partial<T>[K]) : never};

export interface Discover <
Raw,
RawOverrides extends ExtentionForConfineMerge<Raw, RawOverrides>,
Proto extends ExtentionForConfineMerge<Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>, Proto>,
ProtoOverrides extends ExtentionForConfineMerge<Merge<Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>, Proto>, ProtoOverrides>,
> {
  Raw: Raw;
  RawOverrides: ConfineMerge<Raw, RawOverrides>;
  Proto: ConfineMerge<Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>, Proto>;
  ProtoOverrides: ConfineMerge<Merge<Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>, Proto>, ProtoOverrides>;
}
```